# Force VoIP call to be answered

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, voip, callkit

I need to a VoIP call to be accepted by user, when the outgoing and incoming calls are to, from the same person, so the sequence will be

- close the outgoing call
- answer the incoming call

Is it possible to accept VoIP call direct by using

```
 let answerCallAction = CXAnswerCallAction(call: callInvite.uuid)
 let transaction = CXTransaction(action: answerCallAction)
 self.callKitCallController.request(transaction) { error in
 if let error = error {
      debugPrint("VoIP Call answering error", error.localizedDescription)
 }
}
```

When I use this I got error com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=4

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the call UUID for the requested CXEndCallAction did not correspond to an known call. I recommend confirming that the UUID set on the CXEndCallAction matches an existing call.

Comment: I got this error when I try to Answer the VoIP.